# Объявление метода через прототип

Tags: javascript

Почему я не могу объявить функцию в объекте через function declaration , но могу объявить через прототип?

[Здесь](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/med/) скрипт, в котором функция move() объявлена через прототип. Скрипт работает.

[Здесь](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/med3/) скрипт, в котором функция объявлена через function declaration. В результате скрипт не работает и в консоли ошибки.

Через прототип функцию объявляю таким образом:

```
Player.prototype.move = function(offset){
    var elem = document.getElementById('player');

    var coord_x = elem.offsetLeft + offset,
    coord_y = elem.offsetTop;

    $(elem).attr('style', 'left: ' + coord_x + 'px; top: ' + coord_y + 'px');       
}
```

Через fd функцию объявляю таким образом:

```
function move(offset){
    var elem = document.getElementById('player');

    var coord_x = elem.offsetLeft + offset,
    coord_y = elem.offsetTop;

    $(elem).attr('style', 'left: ' + coord_x + 'px; top: ' + coord_y + 'px');       
}
```

Вызываю таким образом:

```
mediator.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

когда вы пишете:

```
function Player(health, bullets){
    ...
    function move(offset){
        ...
    }
}
```

а потом:

```
this.players.player1 = new Player(3, 100);
...
mediator.players.player1.move(-10);
```

вы как бы пытаетесь вызвать "приватный" метод `move`, фактически его нет у объекта, он доступен только в теле функции `Player` и не доступен извне.

в тоже время, когда вы объявляете его в прототипе, всё нормально, метод доступен, т.к. находится в цепочке прототипов

можно было сделать так:

```
function Player(health, bullets){
    ...
    function move(offset){
        ...
    }
    this.move = move; // теперь метод находится в самом объекте, хотя через прототип правильнее
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но я всё таки не совсем понял

пусть метод function move(offset)приватный(то есть находится в замыкании и поэтому не виден внешним объектам). но в объекте mediator тоже есть свойства и методы, которые находятся в замыкании и являются приватными. однако это не мешает к ним обращаться извне например так mediator.init();

Comment: >в объекте mediator тоже есть свойства и методы, которые находятся в замыкании

нет, нету, по крайней мере по приведённым ссылкам

    mediator = {
 ememy: {},
 
 players: {},
 
 init: function(){

это литерал объекта, но никак не замыкание